# AngularJS ng-model for select is not setting the selected="selected" attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have an AngularJS page for editing surgeries, but I can't get any of the <select>'s to show the current value. All the other fields in the form show their current values so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a factory set up with ngResource, this is in my controller.

```
// Supporting Data
SurgeryData.get({'accessToken':$rootScope.accessToken})
    .$promise.then(function(response){
        $scope.surgeryData = response.surgeryData;
    });

// Surgery Data
SurgeryServices.get({'surgeryId':$stateParams.surgeryId,'accessToken':$rootScope.accessToken})
    .$promise.then(function(response){
        $scope.surgeryDetails = response;

        $scope.formData.surgeryId = $scope.surgeryDetails.surgery.id;
        ...
        $scope.formData.surgeryStatus = $scope.surgeryDetails.surgery_status;
        ...

        $log.log( angular.toJson( $scope.formData.surgeryStatus ) );
        $log.log( angular.toJson( $scope.surgeryData.surgery_status ) );
    });
```

This is the HTML for Surgery Status

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.surgeryStatus" ng-options="status.name for status in surgeryData.surgery_status"></select>
```

and this is what I get in the console from my 2 $logs

$scope.formData.surgeryStatus

```
{"id":16,"name":"Ready For Pick-Up"}
```

$scope.surgeryData.surgery_status

```
[{"id":13,"name":"Inventory Not On Site"},{"id":14,"name":"Inventory On Site"},{"id":16,"name":"Ready For Pick-Up"},{"id":15,"name":"Sterilized For Surgery"}]
```

The <select>'s in the form have all the options but (for this example) Ready for Pick-Up is not selected and I have an empty ? option added to the select

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="formData.surgeryStatus" ng-options="status.name for status in surgeryData.surgery_status">
    <option value="?"></option>
    <option value="0">Inventory Not On Site</option>
    <option value="1">Inventory On Site</option>
    <option value="2">Ready For Pick-Up</option>
    <option value="3">Sterilized For Surgery</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are really close. Change to ng-options="status as status.name for status in surgery_status". The "as" will allow you to say what is being stored in ng-model. The other issue will be that it has to be the same object pointer. So $scope.formData.surgeryStatus = $scope.surgeryData.surgery_status[2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) should be the way to go.

View:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-init="formData.surgeryStatus = selected" ng-model="formData.surgeryStatus" ng-options="status.name for status in surgeryData.surgery_status track by status.id">
   <option value="?"></option>
   <option value="0">Inventory Not On Site</option>
   <option value="1">Inventory On Site</option>
   <option value="2">Ready For Pick-Up</option>
   <option value="3">Sterilized For Surgery</option>
</select>
```

Viewmodel:

```
$scope.selected = $scope.surgeryDetails.surgery_id;
```

ng-init will find the matching value from your options and select it when loading. Be sure to set your ng-model equal to whatever value you want selected, which looks like your Id in this case?

Comment: The only way I could get it to work in the end was to modify your answer and add in "track by status.id" at the end of ng-options. and also set $scope.selected to $scope.surgeryDetails.surgery_status.id;

Comment: That's right, you have to track the items you repeat as well, good catch.  Great job on getting it working yourself.